# Search tool to search anything in JavaScript Object,Array,etc

Tags: javascript, chrome, jquery

**Maybe the title isn't clear enough...**

I want to make a chrome extension or for just for the start a function that find a text inside an object, not I don't mean a simple find..

Let me show you an example...

Let's say I have an object like this...

```
Object {el:: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], <-- JqueryObject
        $root: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], <-- JqueryObject
        children: Array[2], <-- JavaScript Array
        _events: Object,  <-- JavaScript Object
        fileSystem: FileSystem,  <-- Object/Class 
        id: "project", <-- String
        registeredModules: Array[10], <-- JavaScript Array
        etc.... <-- And so on..
}
```

Now what I want to make is a function that will search and find a text param in every single item in this Object...

For example searching the text ***'container'***:

***//THIS IS JUST PSEUDO CODE!***

```
'el'.match('container') <-- checking if the text 'el' contain the text 'container'

'el'[0].'context'.match('container') <-- checking if the text 'context' contain the text 'container'

'el'[0].context.'URL'.match('container') <-- checking if the text 'URL' contain the text 'container'

'el'[0].context.URL[0].match('container') <-- checking if the VALUE in URL contain the text 'container'
```

and so on...

Now my question is, Is there already a function that doing that or even better a chrome extension.
Or should I start making this function?

(would be happy to here you opinion for this solution...)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following chrome extension for your requirement.Hope this what you are looking for :)

- [JS Runtime Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-runtime-inspector/iilpjebedgohcmlffhnkhbjhabkdhfmn)
  As per the description this extension allows developers to search java-script objects in run-time by their name or value.
  And allows developers to explore javascript objects graph in memory. You can search objects by property names or values

**Note:This was mentioned by the developer**

> It uses regex to find properties. You can easily hang your browser if
>   your object model is large

You can find his project on [GitHub](https://github.com/anvaka/jsruntime/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: it's a great solution but it's doesn't work on  ver 32 and up...

Comment: @Ofear Okay may be at-least you could try making a chrome extension by going through the code :) ? you may able to get some idea about how it works :)

Comment: As of 2015-05-12 the extension appears to be working though it is not intuitive to use. Must have the elements tab selected with the JS Runtime sub tab (for me it is on the right) and have the console pane showing so that you can see the results.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work, any update?  Is this still working for anyone?